# Determine if there's Network Traffic over a TCP/IP Connection using PowerShell in Windows?

Tags: windows, sql-server, powershell, tcpip

I had a situation where an application was "hanging" in accessing the database. I was able to see that there was a connection by using

```
Get-NetTcpConnection -RemotePort x
```

This showed that there was an established connection, which is a Good Thing. However, I'd like to determine whether any traffic is flowing over that connection. Is there a way to do that in PowerShell, either by using a cmdlet or by using CIM?

An answer for Windows 10/Windows Server 2012 and above would be great, using PowerShell 5 or 7.

Comment: Usually that kind of tasks is done using network sniffers and TCP dump utilities
I'm sure there is a way to have PowerShell digging into the TCP-stack, but not in an easy way.